I'm getting an error when I rebuild my project in Visual Studio
This is the error I'm getting:

Couldn't process file MLogin.resx due
to its being in the Internet or
Restricted zone or having the mark of
the web on the file. Remove the mark
of the web if you want to process
these files.

I changed the file properties to copy always. Still I'm getting the error.


Use the Windows File Explorer to look at the properties of that file, there you can remove the "mark of the web"

This issue may be caused by the file being marked as coming from the Internet or a restricted zone, and therefore having problems processing it. Here are the steps to resolve this issue:
1: Right-click the file in Windows Explorer, select "Properties" and at the bottom of this dialog box you should have an "Unblock" option. Remember to click OK to accept the changes.
2: Use PowerShell commands to unblock files in batches. Open PowerShell, then navigate to your project folder and enter the following command:
Get-ChildItem -Path YOUR-SOLUTION-PATH -Recurse | Unblock-File
Please replace YOUR-SOLUTION-PATH with your solution path.
